# Dynamic Linq for dates

Tags: asp.net, linq, dynamic-linq

I want to build dynamic Linq. Following is my code which works fine for one date. But user can select many dates from calendar. And I need to make Linq for all those selected dates.

```
saleDate = calendarSales.SelectedDate;
List<SaleDetails> saleDetials = new List<SaleDetails>();
saleDetials = GetSaleDetails();
saleDetials.Where(sale => (Convert.ToDateTime(sale.DATE_TIME).Day == saleDate.Day &&
                           Convert.ToDateTime(sale.DATE_TIME).Month == saleDate.Month && 
                           Convert.ToDateTime(sale.DATE_TIME).Year == saleDate.Year)
                  ).ToList();
```

How to update this query?

Comment: why don't u compare the date like `Convert.ToDateTime(sale.Date_Time).Date == saleDate.Date` instead of manually checking each part

Comment: @Muhammad Adeel Zahid, we will have time in these fields aswell, which I want to strip while doing comparison

Comment: `DateTime.Date` functions strips the time automatically and returns the date part only

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Adeel Zahid, I'll do that once I am able to build dynamic linq

Answer (score 2):

You have to build the predicate for your where clause dynamically.

Take a look at the [predicatebuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

**EDIT**

Of cause PredicateBuilder supports `AND` and `OR` operators.

When using `OR` you have to start with the initial value of `False`:

```
// building the predicate
var pred = PredicateBuilder.False<SaleDetails>();
foreach (var date in MyDateList) 
{
    pred = pred.Or(sale => sale.DATE_TIME.Date == saleDate.Date);
}

// finally get the data and filter it by our dynamic predicate
List<SaleDetails> saleDetails = GetSaleDetails().Where(pred).ToList();
```

Comment: I need OR between various conditions, so that data for all dates should come. How that will work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you need dynamic LINQ here. You should be able to check `Where` the sale matches `Any` of the selected dates, like so:

```
var saleDates = GetSelectedDate();

List<SaleDetails> saleDetials = new List<SaleDetails>();
saleDetials = GetSaleDetails();
saleDetials.Where(sale => saleDates.Any(date => 
   (Convert.ToDateTime(sale.DATE_TIME).Day == date.Day &&
    Convert.ToDateTime(sale.DATE_TIME).Month == date.Month && 
    Convert.ToDateTime(sale.DATE_TIME).Year == date.Year)
    )).ToList();
```

or checking on the `Date` property:

```
var saleDates = GetSelectedDate();

List<SaleDetails> saleDetials = new List<SaleDetails>();
saleDetials = GetSaleDetails();
saleDetials.Where(sale => saleDates.Any(date => 
   Convert.ToDateTime(sale.DATE_TIME).Date == date.Date)).ToList();
```